# How to detect the ID of a DIV when I scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three DIV's wit this ID's (#firstCTA, #secondCTA y #thirdCTA) and I need to detect one by one when the user do SCROLL DOWN to change styles or active an animation. *I active an ALERT in this example*

HTML5 code

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="firstCTA">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 text-center"> 
              <img src="assets/imgs/clic-aqui.png" class="arrow-size"> 
              <h3 class="cta-here-text"><b>Da clic aquí</b></h3>
              <br>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS Code

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($('#firstCTA').offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop()){
            //do something
            alert('hey bbay');
        }
        else{
            //do something else
        }
    });
```

Really this code dont works because dont detect the ID. The change of styles in the DIV, only be active, when user do SCROLL DOWN and detect the ID.

Comment: Take a look to [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use some library like [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/)

Where you could do

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('firstCTA'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    // do your stuff (you can use "this" to refer to the element)
  }
})
```

Or, with jQuery

```
$('#firstCTA').waypoint(function(direction) {
  // do your stuff
}, options)
```